# ARVideoNode in RealityKit

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, openai-api

I was experimenting with Open AI's ChatGPT and when asked to give me a code for playing a video in a RealityKit's AR scene when reference image is tracked it used `ARVideoNode` instead of my expected `AVPlayer` and `VideoMaterial` solution. It even gave me an answer why `ARVideoNode` is better than `AVPlayer` on a `VideoMaterial` when I asked, but I never heard of `ARVideoNode` in RealityKit.

Am I missing something or is it just a flaw in the AI?

```
import RealityKit

// Set up image tracking
let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.detectionImages = ["reference-image-1", "reference-image-2"]
arView.session.run(configuration)

// Create a dictionary to map reference image names to video file names
let videoFileNames = ["reference-image-1": "video-1.mp4", 
                      "reference-image-2": "video-2.mp4"]

// Track the reference images and display the corresponding 
// videos on top of them
var videoNodes = [String: ARVideoNode]()
arView.scene.subscribe(to: ARImageAnchor.self) { (anchor: ARImageAnchor) in
    // Get the video file name for the tracked image
    guard let videoFileName = videoFileNames[anchor.name] else { return }

    // Load the video file
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/\(videoFileName)")
    let videoAsset = VideoAsset(url: videoURL)

    // Create an ARVideoNode and add it to the scene
    let videoNode = ARVideoNode(asset: videoAsset)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(videoNode)
    videoNodes[anchor.name] = videoNode

    // Position the video node on top of the image
    videoNode.transform = anchor.transform

    // Play the video
    videoNode.play()
}

// Monitor the tracking status of the reference images 
// and pause/resume the videos as needed
arView.scene.subscribe(to: ARImageAnchor.self) { (anchor: ARImageAnchor) in
    // Get the video node for the tracked image
    guard let videoNode = videoNodes[anchor.name] else { return }

    if anchor.isTracked {
        // Resume playing the video if the image is being tracked
        videoNode.play()
    } else {
        // Pause the video if the image is not being tracked
        videoNode.pause()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a flaw, it's rather ChatGPT's wrong answer. As far as I know, Kudan's [ARVideoNode](https://www.xlsoft.com/doc/kudan/docs-reference/iOSDocs/interface_a_r_video_node.html) is a subclass of an `ARNode` parent class that is used to render video content. It has nothing to do with RealityKit even in terms of programming language - KudanAR SDK natively uses [Objective-C](https://www.xlsoft.com/en/products/kudan/ar-sdk.html) for iOS and Java for Android.

Here's SO [temporary policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) regarding ChatGPT:

> Overall, because the average rate of getting correct answers from ChatGPT is too low, the posting of answers created by ChatGPT is substantially harmful to the site and to users who are asking and looking for correct answers.